# How to provide address to CreateFileMapping / OpenFileMapping

Tags: windows, 64-bit, huge-pages

Is there a function that you can use to provide a mapping an address to use?

I am trying to figure out a way to take advantage of large pages even when I have to map small files.  I know I can waste memory.  Optionally I could use VirtualAlloc to allocate a page sized block which I could then dice up and map multiple files into.  I am assuming, since memory mapping is backed by the virtual memory subsystem, that this is not possible - a single page of memory probably has to be backed by a single file.

I thought I would ask before I did anything.

Comment: The mapping is done by `MapViewOfFile`, but the address you pass must be one that is not already in use. (It wouldn't make sense for a single address to be mapped to two different things.)

Comment: MapViewOfFileEx allows you to specify a base address, but the base address must be at the start of a memory page, so you can't map multiple files into a single page.  However, a page is rather a small amount of memory, so unless you're mapping hundreds of thousands of files simultaneously there's really no need to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it is impossible, but just an idea:

Address allocation decision belongs to `MapViewOfFile`, not to `CreateFileMapping`. And `MapViewOfFile` certainly calls some *native API* stuff in `NTDLL.DLL`. You could figure out *which* function does it call to actually create a mapping, and who knows — that function might be more flexible and allow something which is impossible with `KERNEL32`. (e.g. we know that PE file sections are mapped in a manner you can't imitate with `MapViewOfFile`).

Comment: I think you are the closest answer.  Any idea where the source code is?  LOL.  It does seem like they gave us large pages but not enough ways to take advantage of them.